# Is it possible to load structure and data to angular-storage(or another storage) from a SQLite file from server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, storage

I think what I'm trying to do is very simple, but I'm having a really bad time trying to search this on the internet. I have this populated sqlite db file in my server, and I want to import its structure and data into my web application. This file is generated from another server-side app in a path which is accessible to the web application.

Comment: define `import to web application`. Not really clear what objective is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web application should access the database with its proper adapter (depending on the language and the framework) and then provide the data to the front-end as a set of services. It strongly depends on the amount of data and its variability whther you want to serialize all the data at application load time, or just to provide data access using several endpoints (by using the sqlite database as the repository for your application models).

It's not much different from a normal web application, provided you don't want to write on the sqlite database and so consider all your models read-only.